# How to handle gRPC error crashing Node app

Tags: node.js, error-handling, grpc

I have a simple Express App communicating with another over gRPC, it appears to be crashing on an error event.

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/home/justin/singles-api/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)
    at ClientReadableStream._emitStatusIfDone (/home/justin/singles-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:233:26)
    at ClientReadableStream._receiveStatus (/home/justin/singles-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:211:8)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/justin/singles-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1272:15)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/justin/singles-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/justin/singles-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
    at /home/justin/singles-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1029:24
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at ClientReadableStream._emitStatusIfDone (/home/justin/singles-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:234:12)
    at ClientReadableStream._receiveStatus (/home/justin/singles-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:211:8)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at /home/justin/singles-api/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1029:24
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! singles-api@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the singles-api@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I'm using some minimal example code for gRPC, how would I go about handling this to prevent the crash? as I'm not quite sure what it is i'm trying to prevent, presumably just a broken/restarting stream?

```
var lnrpcDescriptor = grpc.load("./rpc.proto");
var lnrpc = lnrpcDescriptor.lnrpc;
var lnd = new lnrpc.Lightning(hostport, credentials);
var call = lnd.subscribeInvoices(request)

call.on('data', function(response) {
  if (response.settle_index === '0') {
    console.log("New Invoice Issued: " + response.payment_request)
  }
  else {
    //iterate through array to find who paid their invoice and update the db
    for (var i = 0; i < loadedDB.db.Node.length; i++) {
      if (loadedDB.db.Node[i].add_index == response.add_index) {
        console.log("Node " + loadedDB.db.Node[i].Id + " has settled their invoice.");
        loadedDB.db.Node[i].isSettled = true;
        saveDB.writeEntry();
      }
    }  
  }  
});

call.on('status', function(status) {
  console.log(status);
});

call.on('end', function() {
  console.log('subscribeInvoices stream ended')
});
```